# Consistent system of linear equation with exactly one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm given the following system of linear equations which is 3x3 
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & a+b & a-b & ab \\
    0 & a^2-9 & 0 & a-3 \\
    0 & 0 & b+2 & b-2  \end{array}\right]
$$

I need to determine all values for $a$ and $b$ so that the system is

(a) inconsistent;

(b) consistent with exactly one solution;

(c) consistent with infinitely many solutions.

For (a) i got $a = -3; b = -2$

But for(b) and (c) i tried different methods but still do not get how to get the final values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So you're saying you did row reduction to produce an echelon form, but this form did not result in solutions?

Comment: @abiessu there will be only one leading point which is in the first column. Because i could not make (a+b) in the first row to be equal 0 and i also could not make (a-b) in the same first row to be equal 0.

Comment: You can, but you have to add unusual portions of the second and third lines to the first in order to arrive at this.

Comment: @abiessu Yeah, you were right, i reduced it to RREF. However, now i'm not too sure how it can help me. I got x1 = ab -1 - (b+3)/a+3 - (a-b)(b-2)/(b+2) and x2 and x3 also equal to long equations of a and b. There is no way i can solve for a or b

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is invertible, then the system is consistent with exactly one solution. (b) consists of any values $a$ and $b$ that make the matrix invertible. While those that don't are in (a) and (c).

I know that determinants are generally frowned on these days, but the one for this matrix is trivial, and makes case (b) obvious. Which just leaves dividing the two cases that make the determinant $0$ between (a) and (c).

Answer (score 0):

The question as posed is only to determine whether the system

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
   1 & a+b & a-b & ab \\
   0 & a^2-9 & 0 & a-3 \\
   0 & 0 & b+2 & b-2  \end{array}\right]$$

can have values $a,b$ such that it is $(i)$ inconsistent, $(ii)$ consistent with a unique solution, or $(iii)$ consistent with an infinite number of solutions.  This is the trichotomy of matrices, and these are the only possible options.

$(i)$ is easily resolved (as you have done): have either $a=-3$ or $b=-2$ or both.

$(iii)$ is also easily resolved: simply find the set of values $a,b$ such that one of the rows in our matrix is all-zero.  There is only one such value, namely $a=3$ (with $b\neq -2$ for consistency).

Because we are covering all the possible options of the solution space of the matrix, we have $(ii)$ taking over the remaining space.  So this space is for $a\neq \pm 3,\, b\neq -2$.